# Different VTiger Opportunity Types

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Can Vtiger be customized/configured to support different opportunity types?

For example, our company is a SAAS company that also provides training. That means we have 3 distinctly different opportunity types that we need to track:

1. New Sales: These opportunities go through a free trial before purchasing
2. Renewals: We need to invoice our customers and handle obtaining payment for their annual renewals
3. Training: We need the ability to track students who are signing up for a training class.

Each of the above 3 types of opportunities needs to go through very different sales stages. And, also have different information tracked for them along the way.

Basically....I'd like to "subclass" the opportunity object!

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this. Question is not clear.

Comment: Absolutely! Working on signing up a new customer follows a very different process than renewing them each year after that. What I'm looking for is really the ability to track a different set of Sales Stages. E.g For new customers, we provide a demo. That's not needed on renewals.